# Button Width, height

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

What is the best way to go about changing the dimensions of a UIButton at runtime? Width? Height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `frame`.

```
CGPoint origin = button.frame.origin;
button.frame = CGRectMake( origin.x, origin.y, newWidth, newHeight );
```